# I can't figure out level 16 from the "hard" category Lineum puzzle game

Tags: lineum

Given that I found this game on a site for kids, it shouldn't be this difficult... :)

[Lineum](http://www.abcya.com/lineum.htm) is a puzzle game where you have to draw a single continuous line to turn all the tiles green. In the "hard" category (there's also novice, easy, and normal), level 16 looks like this:
[image: Lineum hard level 16]

I can't seem to figure this out. If you ask the game for a hint, it tells you where to start:
[image: Lineum hard level 16 with starting point marked]
...but that hasn't been terribly helpful, either.

Note that it is possible to flip a tile twice if you go through it with perpendicular lines, and all the other puzzles in the "hard" category make use of this.
[image: flipped twice][image: can't flip twice this way]

I can't find any walkthroughs or solutions to this game. Is there someone smarter than me out there who can figure this out?

Comment: Created the tag for you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution. There's an Android game called Unium which is pretty much identical to Lineum (no idea which came first, but I'd guess Unium), and a kind soul has [posted solutions](http://doorsgeek.blogspot.com/2015/08/unium-advanced-level-16.html) to that game.

(One problem I was having is that the starting point hint provided by Lineum is wrong.)

[image: Level 16 solved at last]